# Matching Similar pattern using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I do have a column Name.

The values for the Name column can be AA-123456 , BB-786545 , CC-453254 etc .........

I am using below piece of code to find to retrieve the pattern for all files at once.

**where Name like '[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-%'**

But this does not work as expected.

Where as if I use individually like below it works .

**where Name like 'AA-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-%'**

Kindly help me get the logic corrected.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where Name like '[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-%'
```

You need to add another [A-Z] in there to find two letters at the beginning...

Comment: Many thanks John , it helped and fixed my issue. Thanks will accept as answer.